# Turning off Proxy for chrome incognito?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, chrome-for-android, proxy

I have tested Adblock plus which tries to filter ads as a proxy.

After uninstalling i had to remove proxy settings.

It works generally, but not in chrome incognito mode.

How can I change proxy settings for incognito mode in chrome?

I am using Moto G2 with Lollipop.